# Why no Output Log in R and Python

Tags: python, r, sas

I have been using SAS for a long time and got used to Output Log for making many assessments. Now I am a learner of R/Python and I wonder why there is no Log.

Is it not required?/ is it because it is resource intensive?/ Any chance that this will be incorporated in future?

Comment: @RonakShah I think they're referring to the output log. Been a little while since I used SAS but it's sort of like a very verbose log of every command that's been run.

Comment: "Why are things designed the way they are" questions don't fit in well here - SO is made for specific, answerable questions that aren't opinion-based or open-ended. Logs are not required (clearly). I don't think it has anything to do with resource intensivity. R and Python have been very successful for ~20 years without logs, so I doubt they will be incorporated in the future. Some IDEs provide a "history", which shows you the commands that have been run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python provides libraries for independent use . there is a library called "logging" . you can use this library for log purpose.
follow link https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Comment: Thanks .. this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This a legitimate question, as some types of programming actually require a log.  For instance, any type of regulatory work in pharmaceutical or medical devices requires an electronic record of program execution.

The best way I have found to get a log in R similar to a SAS log is with two packages: [logr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=logr) and [tidylog](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tidylog).  **tidylog** will send messages automatically for most **dplyr** and **tidyr** functions, and **logr** will write those messages to a log file.  There is also function in **logr** to print things to the log, similar to a SAS %put() statement.  Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(logr)
library(tidylog, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# Attach logr to tidylog 
options("tidylog.display" = list(log_print))
options("logr.on" = TRUE, "logr.notes" = TRUE)

# Open log
log_open("Example1")

log_print("Get list of high mileage vehicles from mtcars")

dat <- mtcars %>% 
  transmute(vehicle = rownames(mtcars), mpg) %>% 
  subset(mpg >= 20) %>% 
  arrange(desc(mpg))

log_print("Print list to log")
log_print(dat)
  
# Close log
log_close()

# Detach tidylog
options("tidylog.display" = NULL)
```

The generated log looks like this:

```
========================================================================= 
Log Path: ./log/Example1.log 
Working Directory: C:/packages/Testing 
User Name: User 
R Version: 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) 
Machine: ZB15-5CD00276ZY x86-64 
Operating System: Windows 10 x64 build 18363 
Log Start Time: 2020-09-04 08:59:43 
========================================================================= 

Get list of high mileage vehicles from mtcars 

NOTE: Log Print Time:  2020-09-04 08:59:43 
NOTE: Elapsed Time in seconds: 0.000997066497802734 

transmute: dropped 10 variables (cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, ?)

NOTE: Log Print Time:  2020-09-04 08:59:43 
NOTE: Elapsed Time in seconds: 0.00698089599609375 

           new variable 'vehicle' (character) with 32 unique values and 0% NA

NOTE: Log Print Time:  2020-09-04 08:59:43 
NOTE: Elapsed Time in seconds: 0.0120620727539062 

Print list to log 

NOTE: Log Print Time:  2020-09-04 08:59:43 
NOTE: Elapsed Time in seconds: 0.00692296028137207 

          vehicle  mpg
1  Toyota Corolla 33.9
2        Fiat 128 32.4
3     Honda Civic 30.4
4    Lotus Europa 30.4
5       Fiat X1-9 27.3
6   Porsche 914-2 26.0
7       Merc 240D 24.4
8      Datsun 710 22.8
9        Merc 230 22.8
10  Toyota Corona 21.5
11 Hornet 4 Drive 21.4
12     Volvo 142E 21.4
13      Mazda RX4 21.0
14  Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0

NOTE: Data frame has 14 rows and 2 columns. 

NOTE: Log Print Time:  2020-09-04 08:59:43 
NOTE: Elapsed Time in seconds: 0.00253605842590332 

========================================================================= 
Log End Time: 2020-09-04 08:59:43 
Log Elapsed Time: 0 00:00:00 
=========================================================================
```

That's about as close as you are going to get to a SAS log in R.

Answer (score 1):

For R via RStudio you can look at the .Rhistory file wherever your working directory is.